# How do i animate one marker on my google map and leave the rest un-animated?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
  ['Surfers Paradise', -28, 153.41666699999996, 3],
  ['Currumbin Wildlife Sanctuary', -28.1360762, 153.48855589999994, 2],
  ['Sea World', -27.9560627, 153.42679929999997, 1],
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28.001744, 153.32844),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
zoom: i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

 ;
      }
```

> So, this is the code I am using, what i a attempting to do is animate only 1 marker that i have created, in this case the 'Surfers Paradise' marker so that it bounces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another element to the location array. This element would hold the animation of the marker. Due to the fact that accessing an index out of bounds in an array in JS doesn't throw an exception (it just returns undefined), you  could access that position in all the locations safely (it'd only return an animation in the location with animation).

You can then set the animation property to all markers knowing that only those locations with position four set will be animated (in your case, only "Surfers Paradise").

So, your code would be:

```
var locations = [
  ['Surfers Paradise', -28, 153.41666699999996, 3, google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE],
  ['Currumbin Wildlife Sanctuary', -28.1360762, 153.48855589999994, 2],
  ['Sea World', -27.9560627, 153.42679929999997, 1],
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-28.001744, 153.32844),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
zoom: i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    animation: locations[i][4],
    map: map
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ty! helped so much!! :D

Comment: @J.Dumitru Glad to help! Please, accept my answer if it's ok with you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just check   the location and sue anination or not

```
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      if ( locations[i][0] == 'Surfers Paradise' ) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
          map: map
        });
      } else {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),

          map: map
        });

      }

      ........



    }
```

Comment: also, there seems to be a marker underneath the annotated marker and i can't seem to get rid of it :/. Furthermore, with this code added in my markers no longer work :(

Comment: @J.Dumitru   the for is the loop for whow the marke ... like in your code